# dataGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundObject is not return the expected Object

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview populated with a DataTable. I need to access the objects in every row.

When I access the `dataGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundObject` as MSDN says for fetching the objects in the datagrid rows, I'm getting a DataRowView that I can't cast to MyObject.

Can anyone give some advice on how I can get the objects from the datagrid instead?

```
DataRowView drv = manuteGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
 DataRow dr = drv.Row;
 AEMANUTE manute = dr as AEMANUTE;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is `MyObject`, why isn't it sufficient to have the `DataRow`?

Comment: `DataRow` cannot be casted to the type `AEMANUTE`. Create method which take `DataRow` as parameter, copy values to the new instance of `AEMANUTE` and return that instance

Comment: So there is no WAY of easy get my AEMANUTE object from the DataRow or the DataRowView without populating my datasource with a list<AEManute> objects instead?